# Is it possible to log from a servlet filter on AppEngine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

The standard logging code does not seem to work instantiating a logger with the canonical name nor using an anonymous logger.

Code below:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserAccessFilter.class
  .getCanonicalName());

// ...
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
  throws IOException, ServletException {
  if (!UsersHelper.isValid(req)) {
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, getErrorMessage(req));
    // ... some error serving code
  } else {
    chain.doFilter(req, resp);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can log from a servlet filter - I'm doing it in my code.

I bet you are logging at info levels, while App Engine only reports warning and above by default.  Look in `WEB-INF/logging.properties` and add / replace `.level = INFO` to see INFO messages (or log WARNING+ messages).

Answer (score 0):

A servlet filter is just a class, so you should be able to. What "standard logging code" have you tried?

Comment: Is logging working in other areas of your application? That should work. Take a look at your logging.properties and make sure you aren't turning logging off..

Comment: Yes the logging.properties was the issue.  Thanks!